# Как удалить из строки повторяющиеся символы?

Tags: javascript

Как удалить из строки повторяющиеся символы?
Например, была строка 'abbcdafec', а получим 'abcdfe'

Answer (score 2):

```js
function uniqSym(s) {
  var c = {};
  var r = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (!c[s[i]]) {
      r = r + s[i];
      c[s[i]] = 1;
    }
  }

  return r;
}

console.log(uniqSym("asdfasdfasdfssfs"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Неэффективный алгоритм, но зато есть

```js
var input = 'abbcdafec';

var obj = input.split('').reduce((o, v, i) => { o[v] = v; return o; }, {});
var arrUnique = Object.keys(obj);
var output = arrUnique.join('')


console.log('input: ' + input);
console.log('output: ' + output);
```

Comment: а в чем смысл _Object.keys(obj).map(num => num)_?

Comment: @Grundy случайно оставил

Answer (score 0):

С использованием [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) и [spread оператора](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```js
var input = 'abbcdafec';
var output = [...new Set('abbcdafec')].join('');


console.log('input: ' + input);
console.log('output: ' + output);
```

Comment: Наш человек :) Может `[...new Set(input)].join\`\``?

Comment: @Other, да, так тоже работает

Answer (score -1):

```js
/**
 * @name removeDuplicates
 * @param {string} str
 * @returns {string}
 *
 * Complexity: O(n * (n/2))
 */

function removeDuplicates(str) {
  let result = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str.indexOf(str[i]) >= i) {
      result += str[i];
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145481/discussion-between-alexander-and-grundy)